# Weld DefinitionException when deploying Spring Boot project to Wildfly

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, wildfly, jboss-weld

I'm trying to use WildFly to my Spring Boot project, but when I deploy it, the following exception is thrown:

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"infrendsz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException
    ...
"}}
```

The project works fine as a normal Spring Boot project.

I'm using WildFly 11.

I did everything written here:
https://thepracticaldeveloper.com/2017/09/02/how-to-deploy-a-spring-boot-war-in-wildfly-jboss/

Also my project doesn't use Spring Security at all, but I needed to add it to the dependencies, because WildFly threw a ClassDefNotFound exception otherwise.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hu.kleatech</groupId>
    <artifactId>infrendsz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>infrendsz</name>
    <description>Információs rendszerek építése tárgy beadandó</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>joinfaces-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!--
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    -->

</project>
```

Do you have any idea what couses this and how to solve it?

Comment: You may want to show whole `javax.enterprise.event.ObserverException` exception stacktrace.

Comment: StackOverflow don't let me do it, because it would have a bad code-description ratio. It says "It looks like your post is mostly code". But anyway, the MalformedParameterizedTypeException is what matters. It means, that the class it's looking for is present, but with a wrong version.